# truffle console - return (array of addresses) issue

Tags: solidity, truffle

This problem happens only when I place contracts A and contract B in seperate file. When placed in same file, I get the array elements perfectly

Please find the contract below. I was able to successfully compile and migrate the same.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

import "./B.sol";

contract A {

   address[] public addElements;

   function A() payable {

   }

   function create() returns (address a) {
       B obj = new B();
       addElements.push(obj);
       return obj;
   }


   function getElements() returns (address[] ) {
       return addElements;
   }

}

//  <<<< This is in a different file        >>>>

pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract B {

   function B() {

   }

}
```

Now I am using truffle console and trying to invoke getElements() function to get back the arrays and would like to loop through them 
However, I don't see any array elements.

Output attached.

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to attach some elements + I guess something got wrong when you've copied/pasted your code (see `function B() {[![enter image description here][1]][1]` )

Comment: sorry . I have corrected them now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Web3JS, the function `myFunction.call()` is used to explicitly call a constant function (a function that only read in the blockchain and doesn't write anything). That why, most of the time, these functions can have the keywork `constant` in the contract :

```
function getElements() constant returns (address[] ) {
   return addElements;
}
```

It's unlike a **sendTransaction** function that is directly called using `myFunction()`. This function will write in the blockchain and needs to be mined.

So in your case, you can use this command to read data in the blockchain

```
A.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.getElements.call();})
```

But to write some data, you need to remove the suffixe call()

```
A.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.create();})
```

And the result is the following

```
truffle(development)> A.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.create();})
{ tx: '0xfc66c777e5690f004ef66f3e3733d585c0df947af9131b2b6275290ab5b3346d',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: '0xfc66c777e5690f004ef66f3e3733d585c0df947af9131b2b6275290ab5b3346d',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x24bc2ffb297bb01b116c4a35ed045f521b23f8495fb262ea1e0564d11b562e38',
     blockNumber: 44,
     gasUsed: 104777,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 104777,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [] },
  logs: [] }
truffle(development)> A.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.getElements.call();})
[ '0x0cb0dbf5a387a5b24c4d7160d5d02c5102d80877' ]
```

---

**EDIT: Retrieve a result from a transaction**
You can't directly get a result from a transaction because it's fully asynchronous and you have to wait the transaction has been mined.

However, there is some tricks: For example by triggering an event

You can add an event in your contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
import "./B.sol";
contract A {
   address[] public addElements;

   event newAddress(address a);

   function A() payable { }

   function create() returns (address a) {
       B obj = new B();
       addElements.push(obj);

       // Trigger event
       newAddress(obj);
   }

   function getElements() returns (address[] ) {
       return addElements;
   }
}
```

Then when you send the transaction with Truffle, the result contains the logs

Example through a Truffle test (**./test/test01.js**)

```
var A = artifacts.require("./A.sol");

contract('A', function() {

    it("should work", function() {
        return A.deployed().then(function(instance){

            // Send transaction.
            return instance.create();

        }).then(function(result){
            console.log("transaction:");
            console.log(result.tx);

            console.log("logs:");
            console.log(result.logs.args.a); // Here is the new address

            return A.deployed();

        }).then(function(instance){
            // Get the data 
            return instance.getElements.call();

        }).then(function(result){
            console.log("getElements:");
            console.log(result); // same result by calling getElements()
        });
    });
});
```

Execute

```
$ truffle test test/test01.js




transaction: 0xd2a742751b339b9f6ddc19322e1171de2bef2c9bec22b8a74d5e2952d59bec66 

logs: [ 
    { logIndex: 0,
      transactionIndex: 0,
      transactionHash: '0xd2a742751b339b9f6ddc19322e1171de2bef2c9bec22b8a74d5e2952d59bec66',
      blockHash: '0x4e896578981a332143d43d7de211e5268b2c8a31917a13455709dc713caed75c',
      blockNumber: 107,
      address: '0xdf8904a0349bec7512c83ec13742b671232629db',
      type: 'mined',
      event: 'newAddress',
      args: { a: '0x0c6f45eb4f85e2b5b0b1cc9b08062060c9f6bed0' } } 
] 

getElements:    
[ '0x0c6f45eb4f85e2b5b0b1cc9b08062060c9f6bed0' ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, is there a way to retrieve the address information after this execution A.deployed().then(function(instance){return instance.create();})

Comment: I just edited my answer. It gives you a way to retrieve a result from a transaction (writtable function)